# Non-hooked overlay drawing library

Tags: c++, windows, overlay

I am interested in making a game trainer but I stumbled over the question of making a menu which the player can choose from.  I am using C++ and my target client is windows based.

I searched around and people mostly use DirectX and hook into the game to draw (A little bit like the discord overlay) but I find it extremely difficult to use DirectX.

Here is an example I found:

[image]

I really like the way the SFML library draws but I can't seem to find any APIs which support that ease of drawing.

I once did manage to make a menu in C# by using System.Drawing to draw an external overlay which I could draw to using C#'s brush API, however I prefer to write in C++ as I feel I can do more in that language.

My question is:

**Is the a way I could use something like the System.Drawing/SFML API to draw an overlay over another window in C++ (Which would be accessible in a console application)?**

**Is it easily portable (As a DLL or even including a header)? (Most of the solutions I have seen are not portable and/or widely supported)**

Comment: One option is: Use the library of your choice / convenience into an offscreen buffer, then copy that into a texture buffer and use OpenGL or DirectX hooking for only the very last step: drawing one partially transparent textured quad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Qt for drawing images, text, etc.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-painting-basicdrawing-example.html

It is widely supported, and also [cross-platform](https://wiki.qt.io/Supported_Platforms)

You can create a transparent window and use setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);

Comment: Though it's not clear whether it can be used to draw overlays ot not.